# I keep getting this error message whenever I try to play Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

```
Completely ignored arguments: [--nativeLauncherVersion, 301]
[13:44:04] [Client thread/INFO]: Setting user: gzangsta410
[13:44:04] [Client thread/INFO]: (Session ID is <censored>)
[13:44:05] [Client thread/INFO]: LWJGL Version: 2.9.4
[13:44:06] [Client thread/INFO]: Reloading ResourceManager: Default
[13:44:06] [Sound Library Loader/INFO]: Starting up SoundSystem...
[13:44:06] [Thread-5/INFO]: Initializing LWJGL OpenAL
[13:44:06] [Thread-5/INFO]: (The LWJGL binding of OpenAL.  For more information, see http://www.lwjgl.org)
AL lib: (EE) MMDevApiOpenPlayback: Device init failed: 0x80004005
AL lib: (EE) MMDevApiOpenPlayback: Device init failed: 0x80004005
[13:44:06] [Thread-5/ERROR]: Error in class 'LibraryLWJGLOpenAL'
[13:44:06] [Thread-5/ERROR]: Unable to initialize OpenAL.  Probable cause: OpenAL not supported.
[13:44:06] [Thread-5/WARN]: ERROR MESSAGE:
[13:44:06] [Thread-5/INFO]: Could not locate OpenAL library.
[13:44:06] [Thread-5/WARN]: STACK TRACE:
[13:44:06] [Thread-5/INFO]: org.lwjgl.openal.AL.create(AL.java:156)
[13:44:06] [Thread-5/INFO]: org.lwjgl.openal.AL.create(AL.java:102)
[13:44:06] [Thread-5/INFO]: org.lwjgl.openal.AL.create(AL.java:206)
[13:44:06] [Thread-5/INFO]: paulscode.sound.libraries.LibraryLWJGLOpenAL.init(LibraryLWJGLOpenAL.java:164)
[13:44:06] [Thread-5/INFO]: paulscode.sound.SoundSystem.CommandNewLibrary(SoundSystem.java:1576)
[13:44:06] [Thread-5/INFO]: paulscode.sound.SoundSystem.CommandQueue(SoundSystem.java:2572)
[13:44:06] [Thread-5/INFO]: paulscode.sound.CommandThread.run(CommandThread.java:121)
[13:44:07] [Sound Library Loader/WARN]: ERROR MESSAGE:
[13:44:07] [Sound Library Loader/INFO]: Could not locate OpenAL library.
[13:44:07] [Sound Library Loader/INFO]: Starting up SoundSystem...
[13:44:07] [Thread-7/INFO]: Switching to No Sound
[13:44:07] [Thread-7/INFO]: (Silent Mode)
[13:44:07] [Sound Library Loader/INFO]: Sound engine started
[13:44:08] [Client thread/INFO]: Created: 1024x512 textures-atlas
[13:45:04] [Client thread/INFO]: Realms library version == 1.8.4
[13:45:05] [MCO Availability Checker #1/INFO]: Realms is available for this user
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x00007fff3d2c6c17, pid=4268, tid=7872
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_25-b18) (build 1.8.0_25-b18)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.25-b02 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [ig9icd64.dll+0x16c17]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# C:\Users\Nick\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\hs_err_pid4268.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Using incremental CMS is deprecated and will likely be removed in a future release
```

Comment: Can you also post C:\Users\Nick\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\hs_err_pid4268.log ?

Comment: I assume this only happens when you try to play 1.9?

Comment: Please provide more info. Don't just put the error message, tell us what's completely going on. I'm voting to close this question as not clear of what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

`EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION` at address `0xc0000005` is caused by a memory leak in Intel's drivers.

Until Intel releases a fix for this issue you could try:

- Obtaining latest drivers
- Setting `Use VBOs` and `Use VSync` to `On`
- Using a discrete graphics card